# Post request succeeds in Postman but Axios request to same url returns 401

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have a rails backend and Vue frontend.

my request to `http://localhost:3000/login`

with request body

```
{"user": 
    {
        "email": "userone@gmail.com",
        "password": "abc123"
    }
}
```

succeeds.

However, attempting the same from Vue returns a 401 error.

my login method in the login form:

```
<script>
import {defineComponent} from 'vue'
import API from "@/utils/API";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "LoginForm",
  data: () => ({
    email: null,
    password: null,
    isValid: true
  }),
  methods: {
    async submitForm () {
      await API.post('/login', {
        user: {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        }
      }).then(async () => {
        const result = await API.get('/current_user')
        console.log('current user returns: ', result.data)
        this.$router.push({ path: '/' })
      })
    }
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <v-card class="mx-15">
    <v-card-title>Login Form</v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-form v-model="isValid">
        <v-text-field
            label="Email"
            v-model="email"
            :rules="[v => !!v || 'Email is required']"
            error-count="2"
            required
        ></v-text-field>
        <v-text-field
            label="Password"
            v-model="password"
            type="password"
            :rules="[v => !!v || 'Password is required']"
            error-count="5"
            required
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-form>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn
          color="primary"
          :disabled="!isValid"
          @click = "submitForm"
      >
        Login
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

API.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'
// import router from '../router'

const config = {
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
        Accept: '*/*',
        // Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    },
    xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken',
    withCredentials: false
}

const API = axios.create(config)

export default API
```

I have also attempted using axios directly without the API config with the same result.

in response to comment, logging the headers in the successful and unsuccesssful requests:

````
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"userone@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "session"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"userone@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
headers are #<ActionDispatch::Http::Headers:0x00000001070ab920>
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "userone@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb:16:in `create'
Completed 200 OK in 250ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 9.0ms | Allocations: 42336)


Started POST "/login" for ::1 at 2023-10-30 19:48:55 -0400
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"userone@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "session"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"userone@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
headers are #<ActionDispatch::Http::Headers:0x00000001073c3ea0>
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 208)```
````

Comment: you are getting a token from local storage, and since the user isn't logged in, there is no token there, i also don't see that you are setting it anywhere when logging in. you should enable permission to register/login to all users

Comment: even if I remove this config entirely, and just use axios.post, I still get the same 401 error.

Comment: I'd review the rails log output to see what the difference is between the two requests. I'd guess there is a header missing or misconfigured.

Comment: Adding the headers logged to the question. Looks basically the same to me

Comment: Use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect the **actual content** of the headers sent. I suspect @GreenChicken's first comment is accurate; you're probably adding the auth header before you have a value in `localStorage`. An Axios interceptor is a more reliable method for injecting headers

Comment: @GreenChicken @Phil you were both right. I added : ```Authorization: {
            toString () {
                if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
                    return `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                }
            }
        }``` in the short term

Comment: @GreenChicken if you want to formulate an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the API.js when you are configuring the axios config, you are always setting a token from local storage. The problem is when the user is not logged in he has no token. As you mentioned in the comments you should either set it like this

```
Authorization: {             
    toString () {                 
        if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {                     
            return `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
        }
}}
```

Or just allow your auth(login/register) routes to accept any requests